# Android - Get number from text file online and compare

Tags: android

Totally new here, at least, first post.
What I'm trying to accomplish is that the code reads a number from a text file on my webserver, and it compares with an other inbuild number. When the number from online is bigger, it will do something. I've tried many codes, but none of them are working, so I don't have an example either.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You should show us, what you have tried so far. Maybe we could help you with one of your problems.

Comment: @Christopher All codes are basically rubbish, all copy and paste from everywhere. I'm almost 100% sure nothing can be grabbed from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use the-

```
DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httppost = new 
HttpGet("http://www.urlOfThePageYouWantToRead.nl/text.txt");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line + "\n");
        }

        TextView.setText(total)
;
```

now this number must be in `total` variable. now convert that string number into integer as

```
 int number = Integer.parseInt(total);
```

now you can compare this number with your mynumber as=

```
if(number>mynumber)
{  //do stuff
```

Comment: I now got this http://pastebin.com/peVcnmBa and it still isn't working. Crash while trying to run. I see no useful stuff in the catlog.

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: @Christopher Because idk how to post it... Looked it up. The errors are coming from line 90 (onOptionsItemSelected where I activate it for now) and line 151 (HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);) of the pastebin above. If needed, I can share the MainActivity, but I warn before that is a complete mess.